# What you call the original Cappuccino?

Tags: cappuccino, history

I am a coffee freak and I love Cappuccino. I want to know what exactly is the Original Cappuccino. What portion of milk, water and coffee does it contains? And is cappuccino with more foam as good or with less foam?

Comment: The title is cute :-) Sorry, I don't have rights to edit!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's made from 3 equal parts

**Milk foam** (top)
**Steamed milk** (middle)
**Espresso** (bottom)

as illustrated (bottom left) on this image designed by [Lokesh Dhakar](http://lokeshdhakar.com/)...

[image]

There is also some details [here](https://prima-coffee.com/learn/article/steaming-milk), however it does not describe the important split in foam and steamed milk.

> For a 3-ounce macchiato, use a 2:1 ratio of espresso to milk; for a
>   6-ounce cappuccino, 1:2; and for an 8-or-more-ounce latte, 1:3+.

As to the second art of your question, a cappuccino with more or less milk would not be a cappuccino by definition. However would it taste better, that's down to your personal taste and how much you like foam. Personally for me, it would become more a desert ;)

Comment: Great picture. Would you edit your answer to link to the source blog post for the picture also? Should make sure it's a compatible license or give attribution at least (or summarize and link instead of embed, if it's incompatible). Thanks!

Comment: @hoc_ageah I just found it on Google images to illustrate my answer, the blog I got it from actually just had the image and what the blogger like about the design of the info graphic. However I did find the designer who designed it, so I've credited him above.

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer , I love cappuccino with more foam. But with lesser milk you will get taste of water only.

Comment: @RonakBhatt no problem. If you've not tried a Flat White, I'd urge you to give it a go sometime just to try something different. Its definitely my favourite coffee with milk.

Comment: @ConsumeCoffee sure will give it a try.. as soon as i get back to home  :D

Comment: Where do those pronunciations come from? Listen to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=it&tl=en&text=espresso%20con%20panna&op=translate) for "Espresso con panna", and then wonder how that matches "pawn-nah".  Does anyone talk about a "roasting pawn"?  Using "mock" for "macchiato" is similarly bad; do people order a "Big Mock" at that Scottish restaurant?

Answer (score 1):

### Original *Kapuziner*

The original cappuccino was an [18th century](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Unterricht_in_der_nat%C3%BCrlichen_Magie_ode/XCrSfavJU3EC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22kapuziner%22+kaffee&pg=PT3&printsec=frontcover) Austrian drink *Kapuziner*, so named because the addition of cream made the coffee the colour of Capuchin monks' robes:

> Kapuziner: Kaffee, ein Kaffee mit Sahne, Zucker, Gewürz und drey Eidottern aufgesodst.
> **[... a coffee with cream, sugar, spices and three egg yolks...]**

- [*Gemeinnütziges lexikon für leser aller klassen...*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Gemeinn%C3%BCtziges_lexikon_f%C3%BCr_leser_aller/xftOAAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22kapuziner+kaffee%22&pg=PA581&printsec=frontcover) (1807)

> Kapuziner (Kaffee mit wenig Obers oder Nidel, wie wir sagen)
> **[... coffee with little cream...]**

- [*Der Schweizer Schützenfahrt*](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Der_Schweizer_Sch%C3%BCtzenfahrt_nach_Wien_i/Ie91X5aV2Q0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22kapuziner+kaffee%22&pg=PA48&printsec=frontcover) (1868)

Similar drinks are sometimes still sold under the name *Viennese coffee*.

### Italian *cappuccino*

From the 19th century in Italy we see *cappucino* as:

> Cappuccino: caffè nero con poche gocce di latte o panna che gli dànno il colore della tonaca dei cappuccini e e da ciò prende il nome.**
>
> **[black coffee with a few drops of milk or cream which gives it the colour the tunic of the Capuchins, from which it takes it name]**

- [*Vocabolario milanese-italiano coi segni per la pronuncia*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=PZMWAAAAMAAJ&q=cappuccino#v=snippet&q=cappuccino&f=false) (1897)

### Modern cappuccino

Over time this has evolved into the [modern version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappuccino) of the drink, usually served in a medium sized cup in equal parts espresso, steamed milk, and milk foam.

Comment: See also: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/4933/origen-de-carmelita-como-color

Comment: Nice first answer! Welcome!